# Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 2 found. Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

i want the homepage to have a custom appbar, which i used a container to make it.
The HomePage widget has the following widgets within it :
1.HomepageAppbar(),
2.HomepageHeading(),
3. And an extended widget.

I have been having issues with vs code and flutter.

A little help please. [image: very troublesome]

this is my code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// * importing homepage components
import 'package:mar_kit/pages/homepage/widgets/heading.dart';
import 'package:mar_kit/pages/homepage/widgets/homepage_appbar.dart';

class Homepage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      HomepageAppbar(),
      HomepageHeading(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is from the other two files

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomepageAppbar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
        child: Container(
          // * this will have a height of 100 and will function as an appbar
          height: 30,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Madanrting, Shillong',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    size: 30.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 15.0,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.notifications,
                    size: 30.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomepageHeading extends StatelessWidget {
  var style = TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Hi, Moneymaker.',
            style: style,
          ),
          Text(
            'Welcome back, new products below',
            style: style,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Column takes a list of children, read the docs about the Colunn widget.

Comment: Please don't use image uploads for code examples and error massages. Paste the actual text instead. See [why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10569220)

Answer (score 0):

Idk how to delete the above question so here i am answering my own question.

this is the solution to the above code. I just needed to put the column inside  a container

```
class Homepage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          HomepageAppbar(),
          HomepageHeading(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the Container() is not the important thing here. In the first screenshot you missed the `children:[]` attribute